# Best way to validate username length in JPA, Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am writing app for myself and wondering what is the best approach to validate username/password length while I use JPA with Hibernate? 
Firsty I thought to add @Column(length = 20) (you have to know that my app consists of RESTful services) but when someone tries to add User entity, whose username is longer than 20 characters it causes DataIntegrityViolationException.

I know I could handle this in Spring UserController, but it is not clear in my opinion. This exception can mean actually problem with everything (everything that refers to User entity).

I can also validate username before persisting it to database (maybe create and throw some UsernameSizeExceededException or something like that) but I am quite sure, that JPA developers has already found the way to this situation

What can you recommend me? 
Thanks! :)

Comment: `@Column(length = 20)` doesn't mean validation. It is for description (in case you want to generate table from JPA entity). there are validators Hibernate uses. You can use `@Length` or maybe `@notNull` or `@NotEmpty`

Comment: well.. that has sense :P so the best approach is to create my own validator and validate the field? I have never used validators :) What about manually checking username size by: username.lenght > 3 and <40?

Comment: Not specific validator. Just above `@Column` add `@Length(...)`.

Comment: here is an example:

`@Length(max = 40, message = "First name is too long")` 
`@NotEmpty(message = "First Name is required.")`
`@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")`
`private String firstName;`

Comment: Just to clarify - `@Column` is evaluated by the underlying database while schema generation so it does not fit your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
... 

@Length(max = 40, message = "First name is too long") 
@NotEmpty(message = "First Name is required.") 
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME") 
private String firstName;
```

and here you can find maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
                <exclusions>                    
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>                
            </dependency>
```

Comment: you i get it, but still - when I try to persist this entity I get ConstraintViolationException and I wonder how to inform my client (client that uses my rest service) which data where typed wrond: username, password etc.

Comment: what I mean is: ConstraintViolationException is too general, actually has no accurate and direct information which part went wrong

Comment: You can catch the exception and if it is of type `constraintViolationException` return a specifc message to them, like most of the websites

Comment: I dont actually know, so want to ask: what should my service method return if constraintViolationException occurs? just 400 BAD REQUEST with empty body? or some kind of information which field was filled wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [Hibernate Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/), which implements [JSR 349 - Bean Validation 1.1](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/).

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate Validator., as mentioned by other users above. if you are looking for a sample, Spring in action book has a good example. [Here is the Github source code for a sample from the book.](https://github.com/habuma/SpringInActionExamples/tree/master/Chapter_05/Spittr)

Cheers!